# How can I unmarshal JSON with milliseconds as a property (preferably using Jackson?)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to convert the following JSON into an object, but I can't figure out how to get past the first property name, which is a timestamp in milliseconds. I've tried to use an ObjectMapper, but because the value is different each time, I have no idea how capture it.

```
{
  "daily": {
    "1397952000000": 682,
    "1398038400000": 717,
    "1398124800000": 753,
    "1398211200000": 791
  },
  "average": {
    "1397952000000": 363,
    "1398038400000": 382,
    "1398124800000": 401,
    "1398211200000": 421
  }
}
```

Is using an ObjectMapper the correct way to go, or is there an alternative?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Your daily and average fields should probably be of type `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: Thanks! Created a POJO and put those two fields on, and it works.

Comment: If you just parse, without using a fancy Jacksonesque parser, you'll get a Map of Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map`<String, Integer>` works well, thanks.

```
   public class Pojo {

            private Map<String, Integer> daily;

            private Map<String, Integer> average;

       }
```